# What Does It Mean For A Subspace to Be Completely Determined By Its Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

In the book 2003 "Differential Equations" by Billingham, and Otto, on p.4, the statement

> The solutions of the homogeneous equation are elements of the null space of L.  This subspace is completely determined once its basis is known.

What do they mean by the subspace is "determined".  I know that basis vectors span a subspace, but  I'm unsure if this is what they mean by 'determined'.  Does this have something to do with a 'determinant'?

Comment: they mean once you know the basis, you know all the solutions -- they are linear combinations of the basis elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase “completely determined” here means: in order to specify the exact and entire set of solutions (the “solution space”), all you need to know is a basis for the space. You don’t need any more data or information than that.

More generally, we use the informal language “X is completely determined by Y” to mean that knowing Y allows us to construct or deduce X, where the construction or deduction will depend on the specific context.

Now, saying the basis completely determines the space of solutions leaves open the question of exactly how the basis *does*, practically speaking, determine the set of all solutions — how it can be constructed or deduced from the basis. (Merely asserting that X is completely determined by Y doesn’t tell you how exactly Y determines X.)

But the author is taking for granted that you know how the construction goes in this context: any solution will be a *linear combination* of the elements in the basis.

Answer (score 1):

No, determined here simply means that once you know the basis, you know the subspace. (If the basis is $B$, then the space $V=\operatorname{span}B$.)

Similarly, you can say a line is determined by two points (for example).